# Calling Sage functions from Mathematica

Tags: interoperability, external-calls

I recently found a very useful open-source math software called *Sage*, which provides many useful functions lacking in *Mathematica*. Since I'm more used to the *Mathematica* language instead of the language (Python) used in *Sage*, the ability of calling *Sage* functions from *Mathematica* will be of great help. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Since *Sage* is built on a huge library consisting of lots of open-source packages and some other standalone softwares, calling *Sage* functions from *Mathematica* will strengthen the power of *Mathematica*.

Comment: Could you please provide 1-2 examples of Sage functions lacking in `Mathematica` ? This will also attract more interest to your question.

Comment: Take a look at Sage functions in algebraic geometry, etc.: http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/tour_advanced.html

Comment: @b.gatessucks For example, recently I need to repeatedly enumerate all vertices of a large number of polytopes. In *Mma*, we can use a very old and inefficient package `VertexEnum.m`. Even the author of the package suggested this package can only handle polytopes with dimensions no larger than 8. To my knowledge, we have no other method to do vertex enumeration in *Mma*, not to mention other operations on polytopes.

Comment: @b.gatessucks However, in *Sage* we can define an object `Polyhedron` via LP (H-representation). Then the vertex enumeration is just to list all vertices of the polytope. According to my experience, the speed of vertex enumeration in *Sage* is much much faster than that in *Mma*.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Another example is constructing large scale linear programming problems (LP) defined on graph structures. The most common way in *Mma* is to use constraint matrix. However, *Sage* provides another very flexible way by using the `add_constraint` method for LP defined by function `MixedIntegerLinearProgram`. With that method, one can recursively add constraint one by one to the LP without looking into the constraint matrix. Besides, *Sage* provides many choices for the LP solver.

Comment: you can call Mathematica from sagemath.  not sure this will help in wanting to call sagemath from Mathematica though :)   Now you can also call mathics from sage.